# Which of the options fit the sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual

Which of these tiles would fit the sequence? I've tried to think about it but I have no idea. [image] [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer:
if you cancel out item from left side to right hand side you can get remaining value.
you can go any way vertically or horizontally.
In this I am canceling item vertically.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> If you assign positive numbers to squares on the left of the bar and negative numbers to squares on the right and using B for black and W for white, you get the following:
> $(1B+3W)+(1B-2W)=(2B+1W)$
> $(1B-3W)+(2W-1B)=(-1W)$
> $(2B)+(0)=(2B)$
> So the solution should be the top right image.